# Why isn't std::declval<int>() an lvalue when std::declval<int&>() is?

Tags: c++, decltype, declval

The first of these two lines fails to compile, the second compiles in MSVC 2017:

```
//    std::cout << sizeof(decltype(++std::declval<int>())) << "\n";  //error.  expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
    std::cout << sizeof(decltype(++std::declval<int&>())) << "\n";
```

The error message is "expression must be a modifiable lvalue."

I know that `declval` adds an rvalue reference.  So in the first line, the compiler considers (does it not?) the outcome of `std::declval<int>()` to be an rvalue reference.  In the second line, the compiler considers the outcome of `std::declval<int&>()` to be an lvalue reference, due to the collapsing rules.

Why is the rvalue reference not a modifiable lvalue, while the lvalue reference is?

Comment: I think, because you can't say "7=42" but you can say "this integer over here, current value 7, needs to be 42"

Comment: Do you understand that lvalues are the opposite of rvalues? The last sentence boil down to "why rvalues are not lvalues, while lvalues are lvalues".

Comment: It does not matter as the program is ill-formed (no diagnostic required) if std::declval is odr-used.

Comment: @ÖöTiib It is used in the context of `sizeof`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the question was about modifiability of its return value but that does not matter when the function isn't odr-used.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat an rvalue reference can be an lvalue, when it is a variable for example.  Why isn't the rvalue reference here an lvalue?

Comment: Oh, I get the question now. When used as an expression, the name of any variable is an lvalue, regardless of its type. But the value category of a function call result depends on the reference-ness of the return type (prvalue if not a reference, lvalue if `&`, xvalue if `&&`).